# How to calculate monthly averages using Forecast.io API in the most efficient way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, aggregate, weather-api

In my project I would like to calculate monthly precipitation and temperature averages (min/max) for the whole year, similarly to [this chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange) or average views in [this app](http://weatherlineapp.com/screens/) (which is using Forecast.io data).

I have stumbled quite early, however, as I am unable to extract the necessary data from the `daily` data point in [Forecast.io API](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2). This data point promises to contain weather information for the whole week:

> Ideally, the `minutely` data block will contain data for the next hour,
>   the `hourly` data block for the next two days, and the `daily` data block
>   for the next week; however, if we are lacking data for a given time
>   period, the data point sequence may contain gaps or terminate early.

In fact all wrapper libraries for this API that I've checked suggest the same. But I'm getting data only for the particular day, no matter if it's in the future or in the past:

`forecastData.daily.data.length == 1`

See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/5352qk6r/).

Am I doing something wrong or is there indeed nothing more than one day worth of data and I would need to call the API 365 times?

Which leads to my primary question of how most efficiently handle my project in terms of API calls to aggregate the necessary information for the whole year?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2#time_call),

> If a time is provided in this way [in the request URL], only the conditions for the day on which that time occurred (or will occur), midnight-to-midnight, are provided...

So, no, you're not explicitly doing something wrong, the API just doesn't react quite like you're expecting it to, although thinking about it, it makes sense (to me at least). If you are calling for the weather for *now*, it's quite possible that you want a future forecast as well, but lookups on the past wouldn't normally need any context in the majority of cases.

This does leave your case in a bit of a stump though, as you would actually have to call the API once for every single day in the past (or more than a week in the future). The most efficient way you could go about this would be, as you said, to call it all 365 times for every day of the year. Due to the limitations on free Forecast.IO accounts (1000 API calls per day before you have to pay) though, you wouldn't quite be able to draw three years' worth of data per day.

If you wanted to be able to make more calls than that without having to pay for your calls, you could cache the retrieved data locally and then draw on that instead of the actual API, and depending on the specifics of your use case, you might be able to pre-compute that yearly data you want and throw away the rest, but that is as far as I can see you efficiency going.